# Hyper link to a local html page of an apps from a online page loaded by webview

Tags: android, webview

Suppose I want to create an android app it can load a website with webview. It also can load a local HTML page. I can create a hyperlink of a website from a local HTML page. Can I create a hyperlink from an online page to a local HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

Just point your link using the right protocol

Offline

```
file:///
```

Online

```
http://
```

Example

```
<!-- This opens a page online -->

<a href='http://domian.com/test.html'>Test Online</a>

<!-- This opens a page offline in your assets directory-->

<!-- Make sure the file 'test.html' exists in your assets directory-->

<a href='file:///android_asset/test.html'>Test Offline</a>
```

The above offline access would work but only for version SDKs lesser than 24 (Marshmallow and below). Security grew stronger starting from Nougat to access offline html from anchor links. You can use the following strategy in your code to handle the protocol yourself.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest webResourceRequest) {
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        if (webResourceRequest.getUrl().getScheme().equals("file")) {
           //pass the actual target to webview
            webView.loadUrl(webResourceRequest.getUrl().toString());
        } else {
            // If the URI is not pointing to a local file, open with an ACTION_VIEW Intent
            webView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webResourceRequest.getUrl()));
        }
   }
  else{
     if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("file")) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            // If the URI is not pointing to a local file, open with an
            //ACTION_VIEW Intent
            webView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
    }
        return true; // in both cases we handle the link manually
  }
});
```